# Trigger vs Should in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between cy.get(selector).trigger('be.visible') and cy.get(selector).should('be.visible')

I've seen that they are working in similar way I and I wanted to know deeper because in official documentation I saw only should('be.visible') is explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.trigger()` can only be used with events, but `.trigger('be.visible')` is not sending an event.

It's attempting to make a chaijs assertion in the wrong command, and will throw an error if you use it. From the [official documentation for the trigger syntac](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Syntax):

> **Syntax**
> .trigger(eventName)
> .trigger(eventName, position)
> .trigger(eventName, options)
> .trigger(eventName, x, y)
> .trigger(eventName, position, options)
> .trigger(eventName, x, y, options)